# how to get multiple checkbox values in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I want to get the id's of all selected items, but I only get the first one in the action in the controller. I expected the values to come as a comma-separated list, but no.

Code:

```
@foreach (ICulture cult in await _genRepo.GetCulturesAsync())
{
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="lang" id="lang" value="@cult.Id" /> @cult.DisplayName
    </label>
}
```

Controller action method:

```
[HttpPost("siteAPI/SaveSiteLanguageAsync")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveSiteLanguageAsync([FromForm] Guid app, [FromForm] string lang) 
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to accept a list, you can just use a array or a list to accept it

```
[HttpPost("siteAPI/SaveSiteLanguageAsync")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveSiteLanguageAsync([FromForm] Guid app, [FromForm] 
string[] lang) 
{
   ...
}
```

And if you want to accept a comma-separated string, you can use [custom model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Below is an example:

**LangBinder:**

```
public class LangBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var langs = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("lang");

        if (langs == ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        string langlist = string.Join(",", langs);
        
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(langlist);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**Controller action:**

```
[HttpPost("siteAPI/SaveSiteLanguageAsync")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveSiteLanguageAsync([FromForm] Guid app, [ModelBinder(typeof(LangBinder))] string lang) 
{
    ...
}
```